# Can I change all solution's projects output paths simultaneously in VS12/10?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have a solution with over 61 projects.

There are 3 target platforms: 'Debug', 'Release', 'Release tablet'
There are 2 solution platforms: 'x86' and 'Any CPU'

I want all projects to be build in 2 folders:
D:\samplepath\Debug\ for 'Debug' configuration on platform 'x86' and 'Any CPU'
D:\samplepath\Release\ for 'Release' and 'Release tablet' configurations on all platforms

Is there any simple way to manage all of these paths rather than setting them one by one (it's 61x3x2 = 366 paths to set !sic!)?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this (I run code like this in LinqPad, but you can create a Console app if you like):

```
const string xmlns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003";
void Main()
{
     var dir = @"C:\proj\catalyst\source";
     var xmlns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003";
     foreach( var configFile in Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir,"*.csproj",SearchOption.AllDirectories))
     {              
        var doc = XDocument.Load(configFile);               
        var paths = doc.Descendants(XName.Get("OutputPath",xmlns));
        foreach(var path in paths)
        {
            path.Value = "\"$(SolutionDir)$(ConfigurationName)\$(PlatformName)\"";
        }
        doc.Save(configFile);
     }
}
```

This will make your output directory relative to the solution file (though you can replace $(SolutionDir) with an absolute path if you like.)

Comment: You should avoid using `$(SolutionDir)` whenever possible because it will make it impossible to build your projects using MSBuild outside of Visual Studio. Instead, use paths relative to the folder containing the .csproj file.